# Пробелы в строке.JS

Tags: javascript, строки

Надо каждую четную букву превести к верхнему регистру, а нечетную к нижнему.
Как можно обойти пробелы между словами?

Должно получится `ThIs Is A TeSt`

```
function toWeirdCase(str){
    var empty = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < str.length;i++) {
            if (str.charAt(i) == 0) {
                empty += " ";
            } else if ((i % 2) == 0) {
                empty += str.charAt(i).toUpperCase();
                }
             else {             
                empty += str.charAt(i).toLowerCase();
            }
        } 
    return empty;
}

console.log(toWeirdCase("This is a test"));
```

**Обновление**

Возможно я не так понял вот сама задача

> Write a function toWeirdCase (weirdcase in Ruby) that accepts a
>   string, and returns the same string with all even indexed characters
>   in each word upper cased, and all odd indexed characters in each word
>   lower cased. The indexing just explained is zero based, so the
>   zero-ith index is even, therefore that character should be upper
>   cased.
>
> The passed in string will only consist of alphabetical characters and
>   spaces(' '). Spaces will only be present if there are multiple words.
>   Words will be separated by a single space(' ').

Comment: А где здесь 'ThIs Is A TeSt' каждая четная буква в верхнем регистре?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используем "isUpp" как переключатель.

Когда цикл доходит до пробела, переключаем "isUpp = true" и следующий символ будет UpperCase.

```
function toWeirdCase(str){
    var empty = "", isUpp = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < str.length;i++) {
            if (str.charAt(i) == 0) {
                empty += " ";
                isUpp = true;
            } else {
                if (isUpp) {
                    empty += str.charAt(i).toUpperCase();
                } else {                
                    empty += str.charAt(i).toLowerCase();
                }
                isUpp = !isUpp;
            }
        } 
    return empty;
}

console.log(toWeirdCase("This is a test"));
```

Comment: Только этот код не сработает, если в строке подряд более 1 пробела

Comment: Условие задачи: " Words will be separated by a single space(' '). "

Comment: @grnch Пожалуйста пишите более развернутые ответы.

Answer (score 1):

Мои три копейки. Причем работа функции не зависит от количества пробелов между словами, в качестве которых, например, могут использоваться и знаки табуляции,  и выглядит компактно, занимая всего лишь 6 строчек.:)

При этом в результирующей строке сохраняются все пробельные символы. То есть функция делает только то, что от нее требуется: чередует верхние и нижние регистры букв в словах.

```
function toAlternateCase(m) {
    var even = false;
    return m.replace(/./g, function (c) {
        return (even ^= true) ? c.toUpperCase() : c.toLowerCase();
    });
}

alert("this is a test".replace(/\b\w+\b/g, toAlternateCase));
```

Вывод, как и просили,

```
ThIs Is A TeSt
```

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, пояснить что делает операция `(even ^= true)` ?

Comment: @MichaelRadionov Фактически, то же самое, что и even = !even;. Оператор ^ - это оператор исключающего ИЛИ.  false ^ true даст true В то время как true ^ true даст false В результате достигается чередование true и false после каждого выражения even ^= true которое эквивалентно even = even ^ true

Comment: Спасибо. Раз есть более простая и всем известная альтернатива `x = !x`, я бы использовал ее. Одно время тоже юзал бинарный оператор `~` в связке с `.indexOf` -  `if (~str.indexOf('x'))`, но тем, кто ни разу не слышал об этом (коих большинство), потом приходилось долго вкуривать, что же это значит; в то время как `if (str.indexOf('x') > 0)` уже говорит само за себя.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант без циклов, в функциональном стиле:

```
function toWeirdCase(str){
  return str.split(' ').map(
    function(word) {
      return word.split('').map(
        function(char, i) {
          return (i % 2) ? char.toLowerCase() : char.toUpperCase();
        }).join('');
    }).join(' ');
}
```